# How to redirect URL in codeignator using htaccess?

Tags: php, url, routes, codeigniter-3

I am using codeignator and I have to redirect URL. I have two URL which are as follows

```
https://example.com/contact-us/ 
https://example.com/about-us/who-we-are/
```

I don't have any `contact` and `about-us/who-we-are/` controller name or view in my codeignator project.

Let's talk about exist URL

I am removing the index.php and controller name from the URL.

So my old URL is

```
https://example.com/index.php/Menu_control/aboutus
```

Now new URL is

```
https://example.com/aboutus

//$route['(:any)'] = 'Menu_control/$1';//remove the controller name
```

Now when user enter the URL `https://example.com/contact-us/` then it should be redirect on `https://example.com/aboutus/`

Same as on my second URL `https://example.com/about-us/who-we-are/` to redirect on `https://example.com/services/`

I tried some code in .htaccess but it's not working for me.

```
Redirect 301 "https://example.com/contact/" "https://example.com/aboutus/"
```

Would you help me out in this issue?

Comment: Why you are not redirecting from codeigniter code?

Comment: @Shujaat, how can we do this using codeigniter code? Can you help me out with second option?

Comment: when you use codeigniter, it's not a optimal one. so please try .htaccess

Comment: @kmgkumar what do you mean? The OP is asking about .htaccess, or are you referring to the comment about using Codeigniter?

Comment: I think .htaccess is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my answer. I don't know it's best or not but solved my issue.

I added code in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us/ https://example.com/aboutus [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/who-we-are/ https://example.com/services/ [R=301,L]
```

When user enter URL `https://example.com/contact-us/` then it will redirect on `https://example.com/aboutus`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a RewriteRrule to the top of the .htaccess after the RewriteBase / file solved the problem.

```
RewriteRule ^foo/$ /foo/bar [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I just want to know how to write my URL with your code?

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache `Redirect` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) should work. I think the failed attempts at using it are due to syntax mistakes. The second argument (the one after the status) needs to be a **URL-path**, not a **URL**. A subtle, but important distinction.

Try these in `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 301 "/contact" "https://example.com/aboutus"
Redirect 301 "/about-us/who-we-are" "https://example.com/services"
```

And, as I'm sure you know, but I feel compelled to point out, make sure the "alias" module (mod_alias) is enabled.